# Angular 2 *ngFor slowing down app in Firefox

Tags: performance, angular, firefox, ngfor

I have an issue where I've been using an *ngFor in a table to list data. This usually creates a table that has 1000 rows. When running the app in Chrome, it works fine, but when running it in Firefox, is slows down to the point where the app is unusable.

I know it is the component for listing the data because when I remove the component, everything else runs fine. Also, if I reduce the number of items listed from 1000 to about 100 or 50, the application runs faster, but will still slow down eventually.

I've looked at the memory usage for the application on Firefox and Chrome, and the memory used seems similar, normal.

Has anyone run into any issues like this? If so, how can I resolve this?

Comment: You should post the actual code. Things to check: are you using `trackBy`? Are you using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`? Do you need to render all 1000 rows at once, or can you get away with using virtual scrolling (rendering only enough rows to fill the screen plus a bit on either side)? When you say "it will still slow down eventually", that rings alarm bells for me about memory leaks.

Comment: Other things to consider: does this app need to work and be performant on mobile devices? If so, you need to definitely not render so many rows at once. Also, older browsers such as IE will have much slower performance than Chrome and Firefox, so if you need to support those you also need to render less.

Comment: I have thought about memory leaks, but I don't know of any good tools in Firefox to investigate such things. (Chrome has a much better suite of developer tools IMO) This app does not need to work on mobile. I do not use trackBy or ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush. Also, IE is of no concern. This project does not require IE or Edge compatibility.  Again, I have done only one row in the list and it still seems to go slower than usual.

Comment: Please post the code how you get the data `*ngFor` iterates over and how you pass the data to `*ngFor` and also how the data looks like.

Comment: Does Angular 2 normally have a problem with listing so many items using *ngFor? I feel like it shouldn't, since there will obviously be cases where *ngFor will be used in a large table of some kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently, part of the problem was with Firefox itself. Firefox version 51.0.1 was having a hard time dealing with the large list. (I tried my app in Firefox v16 and the list worked fine) I just updated Firefox to version 52.0 and it runs much faster now.